# How to traverse a mapping in Solidity (Blockchain)

Tags: blockchain, solidity

Given the following structure, how do I create a function to loop through the addressInfo and return the address, ownerName and balance.

```
struct AddressInfo {
   string ownerName;
   uint256 balance;
   bool allowed;
}

mapping(address => AddressInfo) public addressInfo;
```

I imagined that I could go through the mapping as an array, but the mapping doesn't even have a length to define within the for.

Comment: Mapping in solidity doesn't support enumeration, only arrays. You can use [enumerable mapping](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/utils#EnumerableMap) from Openzeppelin

Comment: Or you could do it yourself, just have an array of all addresses in the map (add the address each time you add to the map if doesnt alreaady exist in the map), then you can iterate across that (and use arraay.length). FYI the for loop here could force you to run out of gas if the list is big enough - maybe when using the for loop, you only run over subsets ie. a paginated function